# Octave: how can I colorize an isosurface?

Tags: plot, octave

I'm trying to make an isosurface be colorized by pretty much anything. The details don't matter, but at the moment it's a single-color green blob. I've tried using `isocolors`, and the best I could get was that the whole thing turned a shade of teal instead.

[image: green blob of indeterminate shape]

Answer (score 0):

Huh. And I found something.

Before I had used this command (all variables are 21x21x21 matrices)

```
isosurface(X,H,R,DX_DT, 0)
```

What worked was

```
isosurface(X,H,R,DX_DT, 0, ones(21,21,21).*0:20)
```

Basically, calling

```
isosurface(x,y,z,val, iso, col)
```

I had avoided trying that because I couldn't figure out how I was supposed to format `col`. Were it supposed to be 3 dims, for RGB? Turns out you just need different values there, and Octave will scale them to span the whole color space, whether they go from 0-1 or 1-100.